# Can firebase authentication work with docusaurus?

Tags: firebase-authentication, docusaurus

I want to use authentication service given by Firebase in my static website created by Docusaurus. is this possible ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I want to help you with this problem since I got the same one. However, my previous answer was deleted because I attached my detailed blog on this matter only. I will try to give a better one this time so that the answer will reach you and others.

Can you use authentication for your Docusaurus, yes, you can. There is no official documentation on this, but the key point is that you swizzle the Root component, not allowed to render the content if no authentication state is provided via Firebase Auth since it is just ReactJS.

I wrote a detailed tutorial on this with full source code: https://medium.com/@thomasdevshare/docusaurus-authentication-with-firebase-c824da24bc51
Here is the full source code, you can clone and use it: https://github.com/thomasdevshare/docusaurus-auth-firebase

Just hope that my answer will get delivered this time.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the great effort! it sounds helpful. I'll try it and if it works as expected, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Good to know. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

### Docusaurus Authentication using Google Firebase

Please check my step-by-step tutorial on how to add a component-based authentication using Google Firebase to your Docusaurus website.

[Docusaurus Authentication using Google Firebase](https://iammassoud.net/blog/docusaurus-authentication-using-google-firebase)

---

### Complete Docusaurus Authentication Series

[Please find the complete Docusaurus Authentication roadmap here.](https://iammassoud.net/blog/docusaurus-authentication-roadmap)

In this series, I will provide a step-by-step guide on how to add an authentication layer to your Docusaurus website using well-known auth providers like AWS Cognito, Google Firebase, Auth0, etc.

Also, you can find more advanced auth flows for complicated scenarios as well.